# C: How to transfer bytes bit-by-bit recursively?

Tags: c, recursion, byte

I am trying to write a function that sends a 16-bit word and stores it in a another variable. What I want to do is to take the word, and transfer (write) the data to the new variable one bit at a time.

It would also be great if this could be done recursively. So for instance I have the function SendCommand(uint32_t addr, uint16_t data), and after one bit has been transferred, the byte could be shifted and the function could be called again with the new data.

My questions are:

- How do I extract and write to the new variable one bit at a time?
- What is a possible way to determine the end of the word, and stop calling the function?

**Note: MSB first**

EDIT:

The reason I am doing it this way is because I am writing pseudo code for a device that will accept this data. Now in my code, I am simulating a clock, and the format specified for this device writes a bit to the register every falling edge of the clock.

Comment: ... and why bit by bit ? Explain what you are trying to achieve. Transferring bit by bit essentially boils down to a loop containing a shift operation and a mask operation,

Comment: I am writing pseudo code for a device that will accept this data. Now in my code, I am simulating a clock, and the format specified for this device writes a bit to the register every falling edge of the clock. I'll edit the question with these updates

Comment: Still doesn't quite explain why it has to be recursive

Comment: @DrewMcGowen The recursion comes from my director's request. The question is whether or not it is possible, and if so how can it be done?

Comment: Recursion here looks quite a bit of a nonsense to me. You should ask your director why he wants recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write MSB-first in one call:

```
void SendCommand(uint32_t addr, uint16_t data) {    
    volatile unsigned char *dest = (unsigned char *)addr
    for(int i=15; i>=0; --i) {
        *dest = (data & 0x8000) >> 15;
               //     ^^^^^^^^ get MSB
               //               ^^^^^ move the MSB down to the LSB, assuming the
               //                     peripheral wants the bit in the LSB.
        data <<=1;
    }
} //SendCommand
```

Doing it in multiple calls requires keeping a count of the bits somehow.  Without a count somewhere, you can't tell whether you've shifted every bit off the left-hand end or you just don't have any `1` bits left.  Rotating and testing for equality also wouldn't work, e.g., for `0x5555` or other values that have repeating bit patterns.

Comment: I think this should work, however when I try to run it, I get an exception and then the program shuts down shortly after. The exception is: "0 [main] 56-REVB 17008 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping Stack trace to 56-REVB.exe.stackdump"

Comment: G, not sure off-hand, but I would double-check the `addr` parameter and make sure it's appropriate for your target.  Are you testing on the hardware or on a PC?  If a PC, you can declare an `unsigned char foo` and call `SendCommand(&foo, 0xbeef)` to write to a valid address.